# Is there a cross-*nix compatible way to get file modified timestamp?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, compatibility

Trying to solve this problem I've come up with solutions that are not compatible between ubuntu and osx. I wish to make one replacement command for the following two, which differ in two characters:

osx:

```
find . -type f -exec stat -f "%m {}" {} \;| sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

ubu:

```
find . -type f -exec stat -c "%Y {}" {} \;| sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stat` command is not part of POSIX, so systems are allowed to have differing implementations.

Assuming Perl is available, the following should work:

```
-exec perl -MFile::stat -e 'print stat($_)->mtime, " $_\n" for @ARGV' {} \;

-exec perl -e 'print ((stat($_))[9], " $_\n") for @ARGV' {} \;
```

The version with `-MFile::stat` is more readable, but unfortunately several times slower.

The complete script would look like:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -e 'print ((stat($_))[9], " $_\n") for @ARGV' {} + |
  sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

(note the `2-` at the end)

Comment: Had to change \t to a space to fit the example, but the rest works great on both systems. Thanks!

Comment: @audio.zoom: I used `\t` intentionally since file names very often have spaces and your `cut -d ' ' -f 2` would have discarded everything after the first space.

Comment: @audio.zoom: Also, does OS X `find` support using `-exec ... {} +` instead of `-exec ... {} \;`? The `+` form would be several times faster.

Comment: Yes osx, at least 10.6, supports -exec + ...and thanks for catching that space bug!

Comment: grawity, I'm wondering if you could update your script for using the + notation because I'm not sure if the current script will handle spaces correctly with it anymore

Comment: @audio.zoom: It's just a matter of replacing `\;` at the end with `+`. The space bug is unrelated; you have to tell `cut` to either use `-d $'\t'` as delimiter, or if you changed my code back to spaces, then `-f 2-` as fields. (I had completely forgotten about the `2-` syntax...)